# PHP for loop not incrementing

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code:

```
$todaysdate = date_create();
for ($i = date_sub(date_create(),date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 month")); $i <= $todaysdate; $i = date_add($i,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 day"))) {
    $json['message'][] = $i;
}
```

The counter $i doesnot increment at all. $i remains at `Object { date="2017-03-02 20:00:55.000000",  timezone_type=3,  timezone="Asia/Kolkata"}`

Comment: Try `"+1 day"` at the end of the for loop.

Comment: @shaun tried it. no luck.

Comment: it works for me on phptester.net, prints whole of feb and the 1st of march

Comment: @RobertPounder I get `$json` with 28 occurances but all the dates in the 28 arrays are `2017-03-02 14:55:37.031447` is that what you get

Comment: @RobertPounder I'm using PHP 5. unfortunately, my dates are not incrementing. same situation as riggsfolly.

Comment: If you change the loading of the array to `$json['message'][] = $i->format('d/m/Y');` it does in fact increment the date that way. But for some reason using `$i` does not

Comment: @RiggsFolly $i just returns an object, format returns a string

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks a lot for the workaround.

Comment: It's working here on my localhost - using PHP 7.1

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by RiggsFolly, I updated the code to the following:

```
$todaysdate = date_create();
for ($i = date_sub(date_create(),date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 month")); $i <= $todaysdate; $i = date_add($i,date_interval_create_from_date_string("+1 day"))) {
    $json['message'][] = $i->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

It's now working. The only change was the line `$json['message'][] = $i->format('d-m-Y');`

Comment: What about using the DatePeriod class, e.g. `$todaysdate =date_create();$month= new DatePeriod(date_sub($todaysdate,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 month")),date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 day"),$todaysdate);foreach($month as $day){...`